# DB2 Linux authentication fails

Tags: linux, db2, authentication, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I have DB2 Express-C v10.5 instance configured to authenticate against LDAP. The LDAP sever is going to be shutdown and I should configure the same DB2 instance to use Linux authentication.

I copied users from the LDAP  server to a local Linux host running DB2. Then I did shutdown the LDAP server. After that I changed DB2 authentication settings `db2 update dbm cfg using SRVCON_PW_PLUGIN IBMOSauthserver` (used to be `IBMLDAPauthserver` before) and restarted DB2.

Applications access the database with the username `db2smth` (name changed due to privacy reasons). I can connect to a database with `db2 connect to dbname user db2inst1 using '********'` but connecting to the same database as `db2smth` fails:

```
db2 => connect to dbname user db2smth using '********'

SQL30082N Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME AND/OR PASSWORD INVALID"). SQLSTATE=08001
```

`su - db2smth` and `su - db2inst1` works fine which means that Linux authentication works fine.

How can I diagnose what's wrong with the authentication?

Comment: Did you restart your Db2 instance after making the change?  Are you using a root install (Db2 binaries installed in /opt) or a non-root install (installed in ~db2inst1/sqllib)?

Comment: Yes, I did restart. Binaries are installed in /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/. Weird thing is that when I connect to the database nothing is printed out into /var/log/auth.log. I'm wondering if it is trying to authenticate (Linux authentication) at all and connecting as db2inst1 succeeds without authentication because it is the instance owner.

Comment: "How can I diagnose what's wrong" -- increase `DIAGLEVEL` and check what appears in the diagnostic log after a failed connect. Did you try to log in to the server (shell) using the db2smth credentials?

Comment: I can login to server with db2smth credentials. I increased the log level 3→4 and [this is](https://pastebin.com/raw/CDStSWaR) what is printed out to db2diag.log on connection failure.

Comment: You should add details to your question, please don't leave them in comments. Anyway, there is no indication of authentication failure in the log fragment you provided.

Answer (score 1):

(Since the question was resurrected, I guess I'll add my 2 cents.)

I would verify, if the username conforms to the DB2 naming rules. Since you used  authentication plugin previously, I suspect you could ignore those naming rules. Now that you created the user on the server directly, you need to follow them. Here's the link to the rules:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/10.5?topic=rules-general-naming

I would specificaly check this one:

> For Linux and UNIX system, characters for user names and group names
> must be lowercase.

I was bitten by it in the past. From what I remember the error messages don't point out this problem directly. The message could have been the one you are getting.

Answer (score -1):

a simple answer - user db2smth need the 'connect' privilege --
you can try :

1. db2 connect to dbname user db2inst1
2. GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE TO USER db2smth

See also:
[How do I grant all privileges to local db2admin with DB2 9.7 on Windows?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8127/how-do-i-grant-all-privileges-to-local-db2admin-with-db2-9-7-on-windows)

Comment: "user db2smth need the 'connect' privilege" -- what led you to this conclusion? Apparently, when authenticated against an LDAP server, the user _did_ have that privilege.

Comment: with db2inst1 (Instance Owner / has all DB privileges) it works fine - this led me to my conclusion